# activecell.formulaR1C1 referring to another sheet in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'my trying to insert the following formula into the F column in a sheet using VBA:

```
=VLOOKUP($C2,userOutput.csv!$A$2:$E$162,4)
```

`user.Output.csv is another sheet in the same file.  So, I've written the following bit of VBA code:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3], 'userOutput.csv'!R[2]C:R[162]C[5] ,4)"
```

But, the formula's that get inserted look as follows:

```
cell f2 has:  =VLOOKUP(C2, userOutput.csv!F4:K164,4)
cell f3 has:  =VLOOKUP(C3, userOutput.csv!F5:K165,4)
cell f4 has:  =VLOOKUP(C4, userOutput.csv!F6:K166,4)
etc...
```

how to I get the correct formula with the dollar signs I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3], 'userOutput.csv'!R2C1:R162C5 ,4)"
```

Happy to hear alternatives!